# enable_if for functions with no return type pulled in it

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

I've recently encountered an interesting version of `enable_if` usage to conditionally enable a function with slightly better readability because the function's return type is not part of `enable_if` (see `cleaner_usage`):

```
#include <type_traits>

using maybe_integral = int /* = or float -- then won't compile */;
using return_type = int;

typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<maybe_integral>::value, return_type>::type
traditional_usage()
{
    return 1;
}

template<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<maybe_integral>::value, int>::type = 0>
return_type cleaner_usage()
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    return traditional_usage() + cleaner_usage();
}
```

For failure-case the mechanism is clear (no `type` member).

**But how exactly does it work in other cases? Because it looks like `int` `typedef` field substituted into template type parameter with unexpected assignment.**

Comment: You should actually provide a well-formed example.

Comment: @Barry, okay -- where is a problem with the current one (what is needed to be corrected)?

Comment: @Barry [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05bdc97ab63fc99b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the success-case:

```
template<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<float>::value, int>::type = 0>
return_type cleaner_usage()
{
    return 2;
}
```

would become equivalent to:

```
template<int = 0>
return_type cleaner_usage()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Which is perfectly legal, given that some value types are allowed to appear in template parameter context. I believe these are formally called *non-type template parameters*, as described by §14.1/4:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.